# Connection.start is not needed for JMS MessageProducer but needed for MessageConsumer

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jms-queue

## A - Question

I know there is a similar question but not the same in SO.

I'm trying to understand what goes on under the hood with **MessageProducer** and **MessageConsumer** in JMS. Using the implementation of **ActiveMQ**, I've written a simple **MessageProducer** example to send a message to queue, and a **MessageConsumer** example to consume the message from the queue, while running **ActiveMQ** locally.

**Connection#start** method is needed for sending a Message to Queue. The exact debug point is as follows. **Connection#start** triggers **ActiveMQSession#start** method. This method is triggered when a **Connection#start** is called. See the following debug point at `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession#start`;

[image: ActiveMQ Debug Point]

The problem is, **Connection#start** is not explicitly needed on a **MessageProducer** but needed on a **MessageConsumer**. However, for both examples, we need to clear the resources (**session** and **connection**). What I realized is, if I remove **Connection#start** method on producer, the code will execute, debug point won't be triggered (not even under the hood) and I see the message in the queue. But if I remove Connection#start method on consumer, the code won't execute, that's the question, why it's not needed in **MessageProducer** and the code executes successfully but needed on **MessageConsumer**? Also why even we don't use **Connection#start** for **MessageProducer** even to the fact that we need to close the connection in order to flush the resources. It seems like code smells.

I see that field **started** is an `AtomicBoolean`. I'm not an expert on concurrency and multi-threading, so, may be there is a logic someone can explain why for a MessageProducer, a Connection#start is not mandatory;

[image: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - started field]

## B - Example Code for JMS MessageProducer with ActiveMQ

```
package com.bzdgn.jms.stackoverflow;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class JMSSendMessageToQueue {
    
    private static final String ACTIVE_MQ_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        String queueName = "test_queue";
        String messageContent = "Hello StackOverflow!";
        
        // Connection Factory from ActiveMQ Implementation
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ACTIVE_MQ_URL);
        
        // Get connection from Connection Factory
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        
        // Create session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        
        // Send Message to Queue
        Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
        TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage(messageContent);
        MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
        messageProducer.send(msg);
        
        // Clear resources
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    }

}
```

## C - Example Code for JMS MessageConsumer with ActiveMQ

```
package com.bzdgn.jms.stackoverflow;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class JMSConsumeMessageFromQueue {
    
    private static final String ACTIVE_MQ_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        String queueName = "test_queue";
        
        // Connection Factory from ActiveMQ Implementation
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ACTIVE_MQ_URL);
        
        // Get connection from Connection Factory
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        
        // Create session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        
        // Consume Message from the Queue
        Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
        MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        
        connection.start();
        
        Message message = messageConsumer.receive(500);
        
        if ( message != null ) {
            if ( message instanceof TextMessage ) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                String messageContent = textMessage.getText();
                System.out.println("Message Content: " + messageContent);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No message in the queue: " + queueName);
        }
        
        // Clear resources
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    }
    
}
```

## D - Configuration And Maven Dependency

**JDK** version is `1.8`, I'm running `ActiveMQ 5.15.12` and also using the same version for the client dependency;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The wording of your question is a little confusing. You say, "Connection#start method is needed for sending a Message to Queue," and, "Connection#start is needed on a MessageProducer but not on a MessageConsumer." However, you also say, "...if I remove Connection#start method on consumer, the code won't execute, that's the question, why it's not needed in MessageProducer and the code executes successfully but needed on MessageConsumer." You appear to be contradicting yourself. `Connection#start` is, in fact, *not* needed to send a message to a queue.

Comment: @JustinBertram You are right, I've mistakenly written and updated that confusing sentence. It's needed explicitly only on a consumer but not on a producer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior here is dictated by the JMS specification. Simply put, `javax.jms.Connection.start()` applies to consumers not producers. It tells the broker to begin delivering messages to the consumers associated with the connection. The [JavaDoc for `Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html) says this:

> It is typical to leave the connection in stopped mode until setup is complete (that is, until all message consumers have been created). At that point, the client calls the connection's start method, and messages begin arriving at the connection's consumers. This setup convention minimizes any client confusion that may result from asynchronous message delivery while the client is still in the process of setting itself up.
>
> A connection can be started immediately, and the setup can be done afterwards. Clients that do this must be prepared to handle asynchronous message delivery while they are still in the process of setting up.

The `start()` method has no impact on producers. You're seeing the expected behavior.

It's worth noting that this behavior is a bit different if you're using the simplified API which is part of JMS 2. If you use a `JMSContext` to create the a `JMSConsumer` then message delivery starts automatically. To be clear, ActiveMQ Classic doesn't fully implement JMS 2, but [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) does.

Comment: Yes, however if it is not needed to use the Connection#start, how does it starts a connection on a Producer? To send a message, we need MessageProducer, and we need a Session instance to create that, which has the dependency to the Connection.

Isn't it a bit weird? Because after we send a message, we need to close the connection, however, in the internal field, started is not set on 'true' value.

Comment: I've accepted that answer because it's in the documentation. But I still have a question mark in my head why it is so, what's the architectural reason behind that. IMHO, it's weird that on a connection, we stop something we haven't called start. I'll deep dive into it, however, I would expect an internal private field that I can follow/track the state of the connection. That's why at first sight I've found it weird.

Comment: "Starting" a connection just means that the broker should begin message delivery. This isn't necessary for a producer. As soon as the producer is created it can start sending messages. The JavaDoc explains why the `start()` method exists. I don't see what's weird about it. Why do you need to close the connection after you send a message? Don't get bogged down in the implementation. JMS is an API specification. Every implementation of the API will be different.